# bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx not working immediately after importing?

Tags: python, scripting, export, import, .fbx

I have built the following script to import an OBJ file and then convert and export it as an FBX file:

```
import sys
import bpy

argv = sys.argv
argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:]

importPath = argv[0]
exportPath = argv[1]

bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=importPath, 
                         axis_forward='-Z', 
                         axis_up='Y', 
                         filter_glob="*.obj;*.mtl", 
                         use_edges=True, 
                         use_smooth_groups=True, 
                         use_split_objects=True, 
                         use_split_groups=True, 
                         use_groups_as_vgroups=False, 
                         use_image_search=True, 
                         split_mode='ON', 
                         global_clamp_size=0.0)

bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=exportPath, 
                         check_existing=True, 
                         axis_forward='-Z', 
                         axis_up='Y', 
                         filter_glob="*.fbx", 
                         version='BIN7400', 
                         ui_tab='MAIN', 
                         use_selection=False, 
                         global_scale=1.0, 
                         apply_unit_scale=True, 
                         bake_space_transform=False, 
                         object_types={'ARMATURE', 'CAMERA', 'EMPTY', 'LAMP', 'MESH', 'OTHER'}, 
                         use_mesh_modifiers=True, 
                         use_mesh_modifiers_render=True, 
                         mesh_smooth_type='OFF', 
                         use_mesh_edges=False, 
                         use_tspace=False, 
                         use_custom_props=False, 
                         add_leaf_bones=True, 
                         primary_bone_axis='Y', 
                         secondary_bone_axis='X', 
                         use_armature_deform_only=False, 
                         armature_nodetype='NULL', 
                         bake_anim=True, 
                         bake_anim_use_all_bones=True, 
                         bake_anim_use_nla_strips=True, 
                         bake_anim_use_all_actions=True, 
                         bake_anim_force_startend_keying=True, 
                         bake_anim_step=1.0, 
                         bake_anim_simplify_factor=1.0, 
                         use_anim=True, 
                         use_anim_action_all=True, 
                         use_default_take=True, 
                         use_anim_optimize=True, 
                         anim_optimize_precision=6.0, 
                         path_mode='AUTO', 
                         embed_textures=False, 
                         batch_mode='OFF', 
                         use_batch_own_dir=True, 
                         use_metadata=True)
```

How I execute the script:

```
blender --background --python C:\Path\To\Script\script.py -- "C:\Path\To\Import\import.obj" "C:\Path\To\Export\export.fbx"
```

The import works fine, but I get the error `TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "use_mesh_modifiers_render" unrecognized` when I attempt to export. The full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Path\To\Script\script.py", line 13, in <module>
    bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=exportPath, check_existing=True, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y', filter_glob="*.fbx", version='BIN7400', ui_tab='MAIN', use_selection=False, global_scale=1.0, apply_unit_scale=True, bake_space_transform=False, object_types={'ARMATURE', 'CAMERA', 'EMPTY', 'LAMP', 'MESH', 'OTHER'}, use_mesh_modifiers=True, use_mesh_modifiers_render=True, mesh_smooth_type='OFF', use_mesh_edges=False, use_tspace=False, use_custom_props=False, add_leaf_bones=True, primary_bone_axis='Y', secondary_bone_axis='X', use_armature_deform_only=False, armature_nodetype='NULL', bake_anim=True, bake_anim_use_all_bones=True, bake_anim_use_nla_strips=True, bake_anim_use_all_actions=True, bake_anim_force_startend_keying=True, bake_anim_step=1.0, bake_anim_simplify_factor=1.0, use_anim=True, use_anim_action_all=True, use_default_take=True, use_anim_optimize=True, anim_optimize_precision=6.0, path_mode='AUTO', embed_textures=False, batch_mode='OFF', use_batch_own_dir=True, use_metadata=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "use_mesh_modifiers_render" unrecognized
```

I copied the `import` method from [Import Scene Operators](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78c_release/bpy.ops.import_scene.html#bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx) and the `export` method from [Export Scene Operators](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78c_release/bpy.ops.export_scene.html#bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx). The doc version and my Blender version are the same.

It appears that it could be an issue with the docs because I removed `use_mesh_modifiers_render=True` and it worked just fine.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=exportPath, use_selection=False)
```

because most of the arguments are default.